# How to give vertical spacing with multiplier to the first view of UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-autolayout

When I give vertical spacing to first view of `viewController`, only constant take effect but multiplier is not working with multiple devices.

After setting first view, in all other views it works very well.

So, please give me right answer.

See below image

[image]

Comment: when i give multiplier with vertical spacing between `UIImageview` and `UIButton` it's work perfectly and show dynamically distance in all device.

Comment: You Can't give multiplier like this, Because at First top control, It take base-distance is 0. thus it multiply by any number taking no effect.

Comment: i think @ABK you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After struggling, Finally I solved it using center vertical with multiplier. I know it's not the solution of my question, but I satisfied with new solution.

Image uploaded here.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image: Give the multiplier value like this,]

Try to give the multiplier value like the above image.

Comment: But my question is , "Is it worth to give in first view of the viewController?"

Comment: Because when I give, it displays 1.3 at Multiplier space but can't see effect in design.

Comment: Yeah sure.It will workout for every view present in a viewcontroller.